# Creating Date Object

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a strange issue in my project. I am trying to dynamically insert parameters to Date object constructor. Here is my code:

```
from += fromYear + "," + fromMonth + "," + fromDay + "," + fromHour + "," + fromMinute;
to += toYear + "," + toMonth + "," + toDay + "," + toHour + "," + toMinute;

console.log(from);  //here is log value: 2012,8,25,9,22
console.log(to);   //another log: 2012,8,25,9,52

//Creating object               
var fromtime =  new Date(from);
var totime = new Date(to);
```

When I am trying to alert the date object (totime or fromtime) there is an error: Invalid Date. I have no idea how to pass it. Could you help me?

I tried this:
[Creating Date Object JS](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example `from` is a comma delimited string, not a series of discreet variables which is what the `Date` constructor requires as arguments:

```
var fromtime =  new Date(fromYear, fromMonth, fromDay, fromHour, fromMinute);
```

(Months are 0 based so you may want to add 1)

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating a date in the format of

```
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

You should directly pass the parameters instead of concatenating them, like so

```
new Date(fromYear, fromMonth, fromDay, fromHour, fromMinute, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is

var fromtime =  new Date('2012,8,25,9,22');
instead of
var fromtime =  new Date(2012,8,25,9,22);

What you need to do is use the dates you have and if it's in a string weed out the diffrent parts of the date

new Date(fromYear, fromMonth, fromDay, fromHour, fromMinute, 0)

I don't think JS will allow you to do that.
You give it one parameter instead of the five you intend.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp